# In Pandas, how can I reduce the rows so that I only accept rows of a certain sub group's max values?

Tags: python, pandas

```
a  1
a  2
a  3
b  3
b  4
a  3
b  5
b  6
b  4
b  10
b  11
a  10
b  2
b  3
```

ignore a's till there is a change to b. Only consider groups where  a changes to b, and get max of that group?

final output

```
    a  1
    a  2
    a  3
    b  4
    b  11
    a  10
```

i.e.
b is max of first group
b is max of second group
a is max of third group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `shift` and `cumsum` with `eq` to create the group key , then using `groupby` `sort_values`+`tail`

```
m=(df.C1.shift().ne(df.C1)&df.C1.eq('a')).cumsum()
df.sort_values('C2').groupby(m).tail(1)
Out[62]: 
   C1  C2
4   b   4
11  a  10
10  b  11
```

Then we combine the 1st group all C1 value are 'a' using `concat`

```
s1=df.sort_values('C2').groupby(m).tail(1)
s2=df.loc[(df.C1=='a')&(m==1)]
pd.concat([s1,s2]).sort_index()
Out[71]: 
   C1  C2
0   a   1
1   a   2
2   a   3
4   b   4
10  b  11
11  a  10
```